# How to change date from command line on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: command-line, bash, 20.04, time

For Ubuntu 20.04 desktop PC I can change date and time from the UI by using these steps,

> 1. Click Date & Time in the sidebar to open the panel.
> 2. If I have the Automatic Date & Time switch set to on, my date and time should update automatically if I have an internet connection. To update date and time manually, set this to off.
> 3. Click Date & Time, then adjust the time and date.

What I tried from terminal:

```
sudo date --set="2020-08-15"
```

But it changed and revert automatically within a second (maybe because Automatic Date and Time option are enabled). So for an internal experiment, I need to change the date back to a specific date using the command line or bash file. How to do that properly?

Comment: [Did you try `timedatectl set-ntp no`](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-set-date-time-from-linux-command-prompt/) to disable automatic (ntp) date/time update?